# Begin each new line with a character (unless it already begins with that character)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've got some configuration files with hundreds of lines of data each.

I'd like to begin each line (after the carriage return) with a pound sign ('#') **unless** it's already beginning with a pound sign. I don't want to do a find+replace because I've got other commented parts of the file that aren't the beginning of a line.

So for example, this:

```
Some data #some comment
Some more data #some other comment
Even more data
#some line comment
```

would turn into:

```
#Some data #some comment
#Some more data #some other comment
#Even more data
#some line comment
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Search -> Replace feature, but put it in Regular Expression mode and match on line beginnings:

```
Find What:    ^([^#].*)
Replace With: #\1
```

This will match a line and everything in it, put that in `\1`, and then replace it with a `#` followed by what was put in `\1` (the entire line).

Comment: Thanks!

This works when I click "Replace" but it yells at me when I click "Replace All" saying: "The regular expression to search is formed badly". Any thoughts?

Comment: Hm. I just tried it myself and Replace All worked fine. What version of NPP are you using?

Comment: What if I'd like to do it on part of the file (on a block, not on the entire document)?

Comment: Select that part of the file, then use the option to only replace in selection that's part of the Find/Replace dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Try find and replace with this regex (in regex mode):

```
^([^#])
```

and replace all with `#\1`. (Edited with Dav's feedback - thanks!)

Comment: Damn, just not quick enough :)

Comment: Only one problem with your regex - it'd replace the first character on the line, instead of just prepending a `#`. You'd need to put a capture group around that `[^#]` and then add the captured character to the replace term.

Comment: Or you could do a forward lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the Language to Perl (Alt, L, P, DOWN)
2. Select All (CTRL-A)
3. Block Comment (CTRL-Q)
4. Change Language back

Edit:  never mind.  Won't ignore already commented lines.  Oh well.